# 404 on AJAX get request in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

The button that makes the request:

```
<%= link_to business_domain.name, data_services_fetch_by_business_domain_path(:business_domain_id => business_domain.id, :data_services => @data_services), :remote => true %>
```

The route in routes.rb:

```
get "data_services_fetch_by_business_domain" => 'data_services#fetch_by_business_domain', :as => :data_services_fetch_by_business_domain
```

Controller method:

```
  def fetch_by_business_domain
    @data_services_for_domain = BusinessDomain.find(params[:business_domain_id]).data_services
    params[:data_services] & @data_services_for_domain

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => display_data_service_records.js.erb }
    end
  end
```

`display_data_service_records.js.erb` referenced from controller method:

```
$("#data-service-listings").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'listings', locals: { data_services: @data_services } ) %>");
```

Listings partial that should be updated:

```
<div class="well" id="data-service-listings">
...
</div>
```

Is there a mistake above, or is this approach fundamentally wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: are you able to alert from your js.erb file? and what are you doing by writing `:business_domain_id => business_domain.id, :data_services => @data_services` in your link_to? are you trying to send parameters?

Comment: @user2675613, I am not able to alert from that file.  You are correct about passing parameters, that is the goal.

Comment: what are you passing through data_services?

Comment: @user2675613, My intention is to pass an array of data_service objects.  I am now realizing it is only passing the ids. I guess I have to handle that in the controller.  Is there a better way to pass an array of objects to the controller?

Comment: updated my answer also note i have done minor changes in route and link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the route you have made

```
get "data_services_fetch_by_business_domain" => 'data_services#fetch_by_business_domain', :as => :data_services_fetch_by_business_domain
```

You are making a route with a **get** request but if you want to *send some data you should use* **post** request.

Change your url to

```
post "business_domain/:business_domain_id" => 'data_services#fetch_by_business_domain', :as => :data_services_fetch_by_business_domain
```

and your link_to would look like:

```
<%= link_to business_domain.name, data_services_fetch_by_business_domain_path(:business_domain_id => business_domain.id, :data_services => @data_services),method: :post, remote: true %>
```

You would be able to access data_services array by `params[:data_services]` and bussiness_domain_id by `params[:bussiness_domain_id]`